# Angular $uibmodal resolve with asynchornization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a service that gets data from a server. After retrieving data successfully, I would pass to a $uimodal in a directive. My code is described below

Problem is when I run my app first time, console log shows consequence like

1. debug sizeList outside // `output >> undefined`
2. resolve // `output >> undefined`
3. GeneralHelperService getSize // `output >> [Object, Object]`
4. debug sizeList inside // `output >> [Object, Object]`

I speculate that is due to a synchronization causing (3) and (4) to happen after (1) and (2). My question is

1. How to make (1) and (2) happen after (3) and (4) instead to guarantee (2) have data
2. is there any proper way to implement rather than my approach

Thank you

Service

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('GeneralHelperService', function($http, $q) {
    var model = this;
    var uniqueSizes;
    model.getSizeList = function() {
        var url = 'api/size/' + input;
        if (uniqueSizes) return $q.when(uniqueSizes);
        return $http.get(url).then(function (data) {
            console.log('GeneralHelperService getSize', data.data);
            return uniqueSizes = data.data;
        })
    };
  }
```

Directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('aDirective', function ($modal) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {},
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, modal) {
          GeneralHelperService.getSizeList().then(function (sizeList) {
            scope.sizeList = sizeList;
            console.log('debug sizeList inside', JSON.stringify(scope.sizeList));
          });
          console.log('debug sizeList outside', JSON.stringify(scope.sizeList));
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<div>{{sizeList}}</div>',
            size: 'sm',
            controller: 'ControlModal as controlModal',
            resolve: {
              sizeList: function () {
                console.log('resolve', scope.sizeList);
                return scope.sizeList;
              }
            }
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        template: '<div>{{sizeList}}</div>',
        size: 'sm',
        controller: 'ControlModal as controlModal',
        resolve: {
          sizeList: function () {
            console.log('resolve', scope.sizeList);
            return scope.sizeList;
          }
        }
      })
```

inside .then of asynchronus call. Because its not poosible to put that outside i.e. parallel to asynchronus call

Answer (score 1):

You slightly over complicated your codes, as `modal` resolve basically helps to resolve async (promises) before creating modal window, so change your `resolve` of `$modal.open` to

```
resolve: {
   sizeList: function(GeneralHelperService) {
       return GeneralHelperService.getSizeList();
   }
}
```

Then in your controller `ControlModal` you should be able to access the return data via `sizeList` and don't forget dependency injection `sizeList` in your controller.

Btw, just noticed in your `$http.get` you `return uniqueSizes = data.data;`, make sure you `return data.data;`

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usv2z3v3/) to get the idea